# Matching header row from pandas dataframe with given dictionary for a row and add corresponding value to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, web-scraping

I have dataset of different car models and variants for each variant of a car , I have a dictionary of its specifications (these dictionaries don't have same keys) one car may have different specification headers and values than another.
So, I have created a master list of headers that all my 900 cars specification headers will eventually fall under these 172 headers say (body type, rating, no. of airbags etc.)
I want to create a dataset/ excel file out of it. I am using Jupyter notebook.
I am trying to make a pandas dataframe so that i can convert it to csv file. I am facing the problem that, I have a pandas dataframe with first row as my master headers . Now for each variant dictionary i want to check that master header row and whereever the key matches from dictionary add corresponding value to that column in particular row.

What i have tried till now ?

```
final_df.loc[len(final_df)] = m
final_df = final_df.fillna("NA")
print(final_df)
```

here m is dictionary of key headers and corresponding values of each variant. Note that a for loop is running for all variants which after each turn is returning me a dictionary m for every variant and as soon as a get m for each variant i want to add it as a row in my dataframe.

I am facing the problem that my data values are not coming under proper headers because each m has different keys and master header has different

Comment: Have you tried to make temporary DF2 from data saved in dictionary, later merge final_df with the temp df from dict by column with unique values?

Comment: Basically for each dictionary 'm' i want to check each key with the master header row say first column in header row is price of the car , so i want to find where the price is in 'm' and then add that value here under master header

Comment: I have tried making temporary df too but values are coming scattered means not under right column. I am a beginner , I dont know much

Comment: if you are able, try to share part of your main dataframe (or even constructor if possible)  and at least one item from dictionary